# How to use initialiser list in constructor call to configure `std::vector<std::vector<MyClass>>`?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, stdvector, stdinitializerlist

About an hour ago or so, I have been pointed out to something called initializer list, so immediately I have started researching it, but there is one thing I cannot understand.

If I have something like:

```
class ExtClass {
    public:
        int ext;
        int pet;        
        ExtClass();
};

ExtClass::ExtClass() {
    this->ext = rand();
    this->pet = rand();
}

class MainClass {
    public:    
        std::vector<std::vector<ExtClass>> attribute;

        MainClass(std::vector<int>>);
};

MainClass::MainClass(std::vector<int> varName) : attribute(...) { }
```

The thing is I want this to happen:

```
attribute[0] has {1, 2, 3, 4} of type ExtClass
attribute[1] has {5, 6}       of type ExtClass
attribute[2] has {7, 8, 9}    of type ExtClass
```

and so on.

What I would like is when I call:

```
std::vector<int> a{4, 2, 3};
MainClass mainObject(a);
```

to get the example I have written:

```
attribute[0] reserves 4 places and creates 4 objects using ExtClass constructor
attribute[1] reserves 2 places and creates 2 objects using ExtClass constructor
attribute[2] reserves 3 places and creates 3 objects using ExtClass constructor
```

Is there any short way to do that with initializer list or do I need to take another approach (if so which)?

Comment: Is `MainClass::MainClass(std::vector<int> varName)
{
   for ( size_t i : varName )
   {
      attribute.push_back(std::vector<ExtClass>(i));
   }
}` not acceptable?

Comment: `ExtClass ` has tow fields: `ext` and `pet`. How would `attribute[0] has {1, 2, 3, 4} of type ExtClass` fit inside?

Comment: @JeJo, I think he means there will be 9 instances of `ExtClass` and the first four inistances will be used to create the first element of `atttribtute`.

Comment: R Sahu, that's exactly what I meant. Not the solution I am looking for, but thanks! :) It works! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *[`std::vector::resize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize)* each *vector* of `std::vector<ExtClass>` in the constrotr of the `MainClass`.

See a **([sample code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tX3sIYGLhhR1zexA))**

```
MainClass(const std::vector<int>& vec)
    : attribute(vec.size())
{
    int row = 0;
    // each cols will be resized to as per
    for(const int colSize: vec) attribute[row++].resize(colSize);
}
```

Or as *[@RSahu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56263581/how-to-use-initialiser-list-in-constructor-call-to-configure-stdvectorstdve#comment99143873_56263581)* suggested in in the comments.

```
MainClass(const std::vector<int>& vec)
{
    attribute.reserve(vec.size()); // reserve the memory for row = vec.size()
    for (const int colSize : vec)
        attribute.emplace_back(std::vector<ExtClass>(colSize));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, JeJo! :)

The first code didn't work for me, maybe I've mistyped something. But the second is definitely working.

I was looking how to do that using initialiser list, but this is okay since it works.

Thank you and R Sahu! :)

Comment: @Amaterastis Hmm.. That's strange. The first one allocates `vec.size()` no of rows in the `attribute` first and then for each rows (i.e. `std::vector<ExtClass>` in the vector) will be *resized* to the passed elements(i.e. column number) of `vec`. Where as the second one construct the `std::vector<ExtClass>` in a vector *in-place*, as per the passed elements(i.e. column number) of `vec`. Technically speaking, the end result should be the same.